# How to receive MC40 barcode scanned data in Broadcast intent?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, barcode-scanner, motorola, motorola-emdk

I am making an App for the MC40 Motorola Android device but I am not able to receive MC40 barcode scanned data in BroadcastReceiver?

I have created DataWedge profile and configure the Intent Output Plug-in for the profile as "Intent delivery - Broadcast intent"

Click [here](https://launchpad.motorolasolutions.com/documents/dw_user_guide.html#_applications) for guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have the correct intent action and category setup in both the Datawedge Profile and your application's AndroidManifest.xml file.

Example from the documentation you linked to be included in your AndroidManifest.xml.

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.MAIN" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a better luck following this [Tutorial](http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/6-0/tutorial/tutdatacaptureintent/) that explain how to write an Android native application integrated with DataWedge intents. In this particular case a StartActivity Intent.

The intent filter you want to add to your Manifest to intercept the intent coming from DataWedge really depends on how you've setup the profile in DataWedge. Following the tutorial, you will need something on the line:

```
        <intent-filter>    
            <action android:name="com.motorolasolutions.emdk.sample.dwdemosample.RECVR"/>    
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>    
        </intent-filter>
```

If you want to use a Broadcast Intent, you will need to implement a Broadcast receiver in you application as explained in [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html).